# How to read checkbox selection in eclipse 'Delete Resource' Dialog

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing one eclipse based IDE.

If the user wish to delete any project from workspace, he can use eclipse delete resources feature.
But, when user opted to delete project contents from disk, I have to perform some other operation.
I am using  `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.participants`  extension point to perform these operations.

How can I check whether user selected 'Delete project contents on disk(cannot be undone)' check box in 'Delete Resources' dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DeleteArguments` class has a `getDeleteProjectContents` method which will give you this value.

Get the `DeleteArguments` using the `getArguments()` call on the `DeleteParticipant` class which your delete participant extends.

Comment: I have one more doubt,
Does this DeleteParticipant works when I programmatically delete the project by calling below API?

 `IProject.delete(boolean deleteContent, boolean force, IProgressMonitor monitor)`

Comment: I don't think so. The org.eclipse.core.resources.moveDeleteHook extension point defines something you can use if you need that.